# Open program files directory using powershell and env variable

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

My goal is to create a PowerShell script, which would open specific directories in Windows Explorer.

Some of the directories could be referenced through the environment-variables.

However I got a problem with the following command

```
ii %programfiles(x86)%
```

Execution returns the following error:

```
The term 'x86\' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:23
+ ii %programfiles\(x86\ <<<< )%
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (x86\:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Can you kindly explain to me, what I'm doing incorrectly here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%variable%` is batch notation. In PowerShell you have to use `$env:` to access environment variables.

```
Invoke-Item ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}
```

The curly brackets are required, because without them the parentheses wouldn't be recognized as part of the variable name.